# Shouldn't there be an appeal process for (wrongly) rejected edits?

Tags: discussion, review, edits, suggested-edits

I'll pose this one as a question for an open discussion because the issue really bothers me:

Shouldn't there be an appeal process for (wrongly) rejected edits?

First I have to give you some background for **context**: Almost all of my reputation score on SO comes from answering questions related to Bootstrap 4. Also, according to SO, I'm currently in the top 5% of folks who answer questions on that particular topic. In other words, I actually know a few things in regards to this particular topic.

Now, I have recently made an edit to an old question concerning this particular topic, Bootstrap 4 (i.e. my area of expertise). I'll link to that at the bottom because I want to keep the question and discussion general here.

My edit was rejected by 2 individuals who clearly have NO knowledge in regards to Bootstrap 4. But that's not even the most annoying part. The most annoying part are the justifications they have given for their rejection. Those justifications are completely and utterly 100% WRONG!

More context:

I *as a guy who is in the top 5% of folks answering Bootstrap 4 related questions* initially saw that old questions and didn't know what it actually meant (based on its title). So, I clicked the question because I wanted to find out what the asker actually meant. I then read the actual question. Nothing changed, the question was still unclear at that point. I then looked at the comments. And it was only then where I saw a clarification comment from the asker!

In the first comment to that question, someone asks: `What does "multiple items carousel" mean?`

That's exactly the question I would have asked because to me (someone who is in the top 5% answering Bootstrap 4 questions and actually KNOWS stuff about this subject) the asker's question was totally unclear. "multiple items carousel" is a term I have never heard before and at best this term/description is very ambiguous. Even to someone like me who is dealing with Bootstrap 4 and Bootstrap 4 related questions every single day.

It is, therefore, **highly advisable**, helpful and recommended to add the necessary clarification at least to the **question's title** and possibly also to the text of the question which is exactly what I did.

So, here are the issues I'd like to start a discussion about:

1) People reviewing edits often don't have any expertise on the topic at hand.

2) It seems that if a question has comments attached to it, those comments are NOT shown to the individuals reviewing the edits! WHY? Those comments were essential for a context in this case and would have shown even to someone who is inexperienced with Bootstrap 4 that my edit was in fact, relevant and correct.

3) There is no appeal process for cases of that nature.

So, my question is, once again:

**Shouldn't there be an appeal process for (wrongly) rejected edits?**

I'd like this to be an open, general discussion about this issue but for those mods who are interested to look up my particular case, it's my edit to [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393210/bootstrap-4-multiple-items-carousel).

P.S. 
I had promised to mods to never post anything on meta ever again but have now decided to make an exception for this issue because it really bothers me when someone accuses me of wrongdoings **when it is objectively NOT the case**.

Comment: I suppose one of the reviewers assumed it was an audit. That said: It is unfortunate that this happens now and then but having an appeal process is too much for something that can be fixed by the next editor that has full edit privileges. I'm not thrilled by that question but maybe this is normal in Bootstrap questions. Just shrug it off and move on to the next post that needs an edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suggested edits should normally not require any subject knowledge at all. So from the getgo you're having a bit of a mismatch, because you're trying to solve technical issues in the question in order to get it better answers, but you're using a mechanism that was designed for spelling, grammar and formatting issues.

Some people go so far as to say you should never correct factual errors with a suggested edit. But if you are going to then you simply **must** write an excellent edit summary in order to communicate with the reviewers. They are expecting spelling, grammar, and formatting fixes. They are not expecting one set of technical words to be replaced with a different set of technical words. As you say, they don't know if this is ok or not, because they don't know the words. And (this is the bit you seem to be missing) they don't have to and they are not expected to.

Sometimes my edit summary is "brought in details from comments." (With luck, this causes the reviewer to open the question in a new tab to see the comments.) In your case it might be "replacing user's description with the accepted term in [tag]." But be aware, some people will reject the edit for trying to change the author's intent. You might do better just adding a clarifying synonym rather than replacing their home-rolled word with the industry real word. You will have to be cautious. You're not in standard suggesting-edit territory. Understanding that will help you understand why your edit was rejected.

Comment: *Suggested edits should normally not require any subject knowledge at all.* That really depends on your preferences for editing... It's perfectly valid for users to add actual content to answers in a suggested edit - just as it's OK for them to add this if they have the edit privilege. They don't **just** have to be for fixing typos/grammar/spelling/formatting.

Comment: Yes and no, @Catija. Say the question is "how many legs does a cow have?" and someone answers "3". Using a suggested edit to change this to 4 would clearly conflict with the author's intent. The help says you can  "clarify the meaning of a post without changing it" and "correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages" - which is not the same as adding a lot of technical content or doing something that requires reviewers to understand the subject area. Because they don't. Which is fine.

Answer (score 6):

I will ignore all the background noise and answer the actual question which is in the title:

> Shouldn't there be an appeal process for (wrongly) rejected edits?

The answer in my opinion is: no, there shouldn't, we don't need such a process.

If you really believe your edit is correct, you can try again, this time explaining in the edit summary why it's correct. Usually on sites with enough reviewers, other users will review it, with clean slate.

However, **do not try it more than twice** in case the second attempt was rejected as well, that would already be wasting the reviewers time, and most likely really an invalid edit, even if you think it's valid. The high rep users on each site has the power to decide those things.

You can also become such high rep user yourself, getting 2k reputation isn't impossible. Once you get it, you can edit anything without the need for approval. By then you also might understand why something you considered valid as low rep user is actually invalid for the site.

Comment: This is wrong in my opinion. [The FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) says that it's better to ask in chat why they rejected it. (This isn't a policy concern, like a signature or irrelevant tags, so you shouldn't flag for a mod.)

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: This answer does not recommend "simply" trying again, as the FAQ condemns, but instead trying again *with more clarification*. The FAQ should be amended to allow for that, and I'll probably make the edit myself when I have a good chance

Comment: @NathanTuggy In practice, the edits are still rejected anyway. I actually did this a few times as the anonymous editor, and the vast majority of the time it was once again rejected. (The 1-2 times where it didn't happen was when a CM intervened.)

Comment: Also, after reading "If you really believe your edit is correct you can try again", my eyes stop. It's possible that many people reading this will not bother to read the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: If someone isn't going to bother reading the rest of a single sentence that explains how to do it right, running into a suggested edit ban is the best thing they can do for the site.